# SQL Server Full Text Search with Apostrophe

Tags: mysql

Any know how can I do a search in SQL with including apostrophes? For example: I want to search a username o'connel in the database with sql.

Comment: To clarify: "SQL Server" normally implies Microsoft. "Full Text Search" is a feature of MS SQL. Or do you want to search text in MySQL?

Comment: Search test in MySQL, and the the search value is contains with apostrophe

Comment: Standard SQL then... see my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double up the quote for normal strings in SQL. Please see my comment though.

```
...WHERE name = 'O''Connel'
```